# SQL SELECT multiple with sum

Tags: sql, select, sum

I'm trying to do a select SUM while doing other selects at the same. My current script:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,SUM(Trackingnumbers.Shipment_Cost) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Trackingnumbers
ON Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6) AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
Group By Orders.OrderID
```

I want to SELECT more columns, but I cannot because I am using the SUM function so it doesn't work, how can I separate the sum functions from the rest of the attributes so the CSV file has all of the columns plus the SUM of `Trackingnumber.Shipment_Cost` in one column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a subquery.

```sql
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(Shipment_Cost)
        FROM Trackingnumbers
        WHERE Trackingnumbers.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
    ) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6)
    AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
```

Comment: Where would I put the other item to select?

Comment: @user1090389 I'm assuming you just want the columns in the `Orders` table, which should be covered by `*` or by your own selection of columns from that table.

Comment: I tried to put my own in but it wouldn't work. It worked with the *, but when I replaced the * with `Orders.SalesRepCustomerID,Orders.COGS` it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1090389 Try just selecting those two columns (`SalesRepCustomerID` and `COGS`), then everything from the `FROM` clause onward. If that works, then try introducing the subquery after it (which should work).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, this is something like what I'm trying to accomplish: `SELECT Orders.Total_Payment_Received,Orders.SalesTax1,Orders.COGS
  ,(
        SELECT SUM(Shipment_Cost)
        FROM Trackingnumbers
        WHERE Trackingnumbers.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
    ) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6)
    AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received` 
I don't want the other columns to be a part of the SUM, I just want them exported. Exactly the way you wrote, just without the star

Comment: And in it's place, the columns I select.

Comment: @user1090389 You can remove the star and put in any column(s) of your own selection without incident; using named columns in place of the `*` has no effect on the `Shipping_Cost` subquery. What error does your RDBMS give you when you run your query? (I mentioned my above comment to see if there was an error in the naming of the columns, since selecting all columns works.)

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is that you are using an aggregation query (with GROUP BY). That means the columns you return should normally be either the result of an aggregate function or something with which you are grouping.

Depending on the platform you are using, some have a "First" function which can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple different ways to get it.

I. Apply an aggregate function to every column that you want to have in your result

```sql
SELECT Orders.OrderID, MAX(Orders.ShipDate) As ShipDate, MAX(Orders.OrderStatus) As OrderStatus, SUM(Trackingnumbers.Shipment_Cost) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Trackingnumbers
ON Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6) AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
Group By Orders.OrderID
```

II. Put all the field in the GROUP BY clause

```sql
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.ShipDate, Orders.OrderStatus, SUM(Trackingnumbers.Shipment_Cost) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Trackingnumbers
ON Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6) AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
```

III. Use a subquery

```sql
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(Trackingnumbers.Shipment_Cost)
FROM Trackingnumbers
WHERE TrackingNumbers.OrderID=Orders.OrderID) AS Shipping_Cost
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6) AND    Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received FROM Orders
```

Comment: Can't seem to get the SQL formatting right, tried lang-sql inside it but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do another query base on your query result, like this:

```
select b.aaa,b.bbb from (
    SELECT Orders.OrderID,SUM(Trackingnumbers.Shipment_Cost) AS Shipping_Cost
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Trackingnumbers
ON Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND Orders.ShipDate > (GETDATE()-6) AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
Group By Orders.OrderID) as a,Orders b where a.OrderID = b.OrderID.
```